# PHP build multiple lines of text from an array, and then write them to file efficiently

Tags: php, arrays, file, batch-processing

So if I were to have an array similar to the following:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [Name] => Ron
        [Date] => 9/23/10
        [Title] => Boss
        [Activity] => Soccer
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [Name] => Tim
        [Date] => 9/23/10
        [Title] => player
        [Activity] => Soccer
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [Name] => Jim
        [Date] => 9/23/10
        [Title] => manager
        [Activity] => Soccer
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [Name] => Lud
        [Date] => 9/23/10
        [Title] => employee
        [Activity] => Soccer
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [Name] => Ron
        [Date] => 9/23/10
        [Title] => sub boss
        [Activity] => Soccer
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [Name] => Lev
        [Date] => 9/23/10
        [Title] => mini boss
        [Activity] => Soccer
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [Name] => Timpthy
        [Date] => 9/23/10
        [Title] => super boss
        [Activity] => Soccer
    )

[7] => Array
    (
        [Name] => Jimbo
        [Date] => 9/23/10
        [Title] => final battle
        [Activity] => Soccer
    )

[8] => Array
    (
        [Name] => El
        [Date] => 9/23/10
        [Title] => link
        [Activity] => Soccer
    )

)
```

But MASSIVE, and I wanted to go through each array element and format the data in such a manner:

```
Name|Date|||||Title||||||||||Activity|||||||||||||||
Name|Date|||||Title||||||||||Activity|||||||||||||||
Name|Date|||||Title||||||||||Activity|||||||||||||||
Name|Date|||||Title||||||||||Activity|||||||||||||||
Name|Date|||||Title||||||||||Activity|||||||||||||||
```

(basically a CSV but with multiple different delimiters)

and then I wanted to write these strings to a .txt file, what would be the most efficient way to do that? Would a simple foreach loop do the trick?

Also, I'm having trouble finding a way to process each unique set of values to a String - so I'm having trouble figuring out how to, say, get

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [Name] => Ron
        [Date] => 9/23/10
        [Title] => Boss
        [Activity] => Soccer
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [Name] => Tim
        [Date] => 9/23/10
        [Title] => player
        [Activity] => Soccer
    )
```

to output

```
Ron|9/23/10|||||Boss||||||||||Soccer|||||||||||||||
Tim|9/23/10|||||player||||||||||Soccer|||||||||||||||
```

Here is my best guess:

```
$finalstring;
$tempstring;

foreach($Array as $key)
{
    $i = 0;
    foreach($Array as $value)
    {
        $i+= 1;
        if($i == 1)
        {           
            $tempstring  . $value. "|";
        }
        if($i == 2)
        {           
            $tempstring  . $value . "|||||";
        }
        if($i == 3)
        {           
            $tempstring  . $value . "||||||||||";
        }
        if($i == 4)
        {           
            $tempstring  . $value . "|||||||||||||||||";
        }

    }
    $finalstring . $tempstring . "/n";
}

$fh = fopen("text.txt", "w");
fwrite($fh, $finalstring);
```

Is there an easy function that will allow me to format each of these value sets as a pre-formatted string, and then write those strings to a file efficiently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for a space saving solution or efficiency ?
For the second case, you can simply use json (json_encode).

(For first case, use only a simple separator, you can use a blank character).

Comment: I'm looking for efficiency and elegance (because Im vain about my code at the end of the day)... I'll look into json and see what I can do with it, thanks for the pointer!